# Instagram Access token - "you must provide a valid client_secret and code" error

Tags: instagram-api, facebook-authentication, instagram-graph-api

Using Instagram Basic Display over a test app.

**Step 1**.
redirect to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&response_type=code&scope=user_profile,user_media` with properly set all query params

**Step 2**.
User allow information sharing with app

**Step 3**.
Capture code and POST `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` with the following form data:

```
client_id = {client-id}
client_secret = {client-secret}
code = {query-param-code}
grant_type = authorization_code
redirect_uri = {step-1-redirect-uri}
```

**Result:**
Error 400: `you must provide a valid client_secret and code`. But randomly and VERY rare the request works and the `access_token` is returned. The ratio is about 99% error 1% success, if less.

**Extra info:**
tried `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` as well.

Comment: Is it possible the `code` you are using has surpassed it's 1 hour TTL? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#authorization-codes

Comment: @AndrewL not the case. I'm doing the request right away

Comment: In that case I'd suggest submitting a bug report at https://business.facebook.com/direct-support/ or http://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create

Comment: Thanks, I already did.

Comment: Link to bug report other users https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/463564131593807/

Comment: That's mine :) .